# how can I close the shell buffer? Prefferbly under a certain condition.

Tags: autocmd, terminal

I have written a `python` script that is doing some checks for a `LaTeX` file and then compiles it. I call it upon saving the file using the following line

```
:autocmd BufWritePost * !~/.vim/latex_compiler.py <afile>
```

how can I close the terminal buffer upon certain condition?